# How do you export indices for Json geometry

Tags: json, webgl, maxscript

I wrote a script in MaxScript that succesfully exports the vertex positions of my mesh. The vertices are  sorted following 3dsMax index order. How am I supposed to write the indices so that a webgl application can read the correct order and build back the original triangles?

In other words, if I type print to my output file the indices of the mesh I get: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc... which is not the correct order for webgl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not versed in WebGL but I'm confident that vertex positions aren't sufficient, you need to know how each face is built, and its normal(s).

You could collect positions of vertices, then get the vertices that make up each face in the order it is to be built. In some cases, you need to know what the closing vertex is so you might want to add it to the array (I included as a fourth id).

For instance:

```
normals = #(#(0.07, 0.01, 0.07), #(0.0, 1,.0, 0.0), etc...)
vertices = #(#(102.003, 200.44, 4598.93), #(405.77, 234.65, 4599.01), etc...)
faces = #(#(32, 35, 33, 32), #(512, 423, 511, 512), etc..)
```

I'd recommend dumping to a dictionary containing all of this information, and a mapping your face or vertex positions. For instance:

```
{
    'normals' : {'32': [0.07, 0.01, 0.07], '33': [0.0, 1,.0, 0.0], etc.. },
    'vertices' : {'32': [102.003, 200.44, 4598.93], 33: [405.77, 234.65, 4599.01], etc...},
    'faces': {'152': [32, 35, 33, 32], '153': [512, 423, 511, 512], etc... }
}
```

In terms of geometry building those are the essentials.

Hopefully this helps you get on the right track.

EDIT: after reading this https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3

You might want to write it out in that specific format.

Comment: Seeing other scripts and looking at your answer, Klaudikus,another question arises. Shall I export face indices or vertex indices?

Comment: Well in the link provided, the vertex indices are implied, since your vertex list is really made up of coordinates. So the first three coordinates, belong to vertex with index 0, list index 3 through 5 values are the x y and z coordinates that belong to vertex 1, etc. In the case of faces, you don't really need their index. You simply need to know what verts make each face, and what their coordinates and normals are. The format I make reference, includes all of that information.